# Login pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Instalei o pgAdmin 4 no Debian e ao acessar a tela de login ele me pede email e senha. Eu esperava que ele pedisse o usuário "postgres" e a senha. Gostaria de saber como cadastrar este email para fazer o login.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegue colocar uma imagem da requisição?

Comment: por acaso é esse pgAdmin ? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgadmin_login.html

Comment: é este mesmo. Editei e coloquei a imagem.

Comment: me parece ser web, é ? qual servidor ?

Comment: Sim. É PostgreSQL 9.6. No Linux o pgAdmin roda pelo navegador.

Comment: então o email, deve ser o usuário do servidor web que está rodando o pgadmin

Comment: o usuario padrão no lugar do email foi a primeira coisa que tentei.

Comment: Sua intenção é usar o Web mesmo? Porque no linux também tem o cliente do pgAdmin 4 (instalado por pip)